# File not found when using multiple scanners

Tags: java, file, input, java.util.scanner

I'm writing a simple program in Eclipse to input and compare two text files. However, I can't seem to import the two text files at the same time. If I delete one of the new scanner objects, it clears my other file; otherwise, it gives me an error that the file was not found on both. Both files are in the same place in my source folder. The code is as follows:

```
textfile1 = new File("Text1.txt");
Scanner text1 = new Scanner(textfile1);
textfile2 = new File("Text2.txt");
Scanner text2 = new Scanner(textfile2);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check this link here you will find the program using which we can compare content of different files.  http://www.simplecodestuffs.com/compare-two-files-by-content-in-java/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code with the try-catch block and let me know if it worked or not.

```js
// sometimes the compiler complains if there was a scanner opened without a try-catch block around it
try {
            final File FILE1 = new File("text1.txt"); //it is always a good thing to make a file as final, it gives an easy reference for the reader 
            final File FILE2 = new File("text2.txt");
            Scanner t1 = new Scanner(FILE1);
            Scanner t2 = new Scanner(FILE2);
            //after you are done close the scanner
            t1.close();
            t2.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        }
```

Comment: Great, I am glad it worked for you! Would you please then close this question by checking my answer? @Kevin